# Change owner of external hard drive partition from root to user

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 16.04.2.
System boot from Internal HD.
User name is 'ale'
Everything looks great, so far.

I have connected an External HD named as 'Aquarius'
When boot this EHD is mounted with 'root', since at File Properties at tab Permissions, it says `Owner:root, Group: root`

From terminal I run: `sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/Aquarius`
and then I run: `sudo chown -R ale:ale /mnt/Aquarius`
but I got the message 'chown changing ownership operation not permitted'

Answer (score 2):

Some filesystems (e.g., FAT32) don't support per-file owners, groups, or permissions. You can only set permissions on them filesystem-wide, and you do so via a mount option: `mount -o uid=123,gid=123,umask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/Aquarius`

Source: [`man mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)