# Can't edit mounted drive from VSCode

Tags: permissions, mount, visual-studio-code

### Context

I do programming on a) a Mac computer, and b) an Ubuntu computer running off a 1 TB HDD that I boot from the Mac via USB. This works completely fine. However, I have my code on a 16GB FAT32 partition so I can write code from both computers. This works fine on the Mac, but I run into a problem on Ubuntu.

### Problem

In VSCode on Ubuntu, when I attempt to do anything to the mounted partition (edit, rename, create, etc.) I get some sort of error.

1. When I try to create a new file: `Unable to write file (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open)`
2. When I try to edit a file, I am prompted to "Retry as sudo," which works, but I have to enter my password anytime I edit any file, which is extremely inconvenient.
3. When I try to create a new directory, I get `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir`
4. et cetera

### Details

I used `sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/src` to mount the drive.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

My VSCode version is 1.46.1

### Attempts to resolve

I tried the following:

```sh
sudo chmod a+rw ~/src
```

This above one doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't solve the problem either.

```sh
 In: sudo chown $USER:$USER -R ~/src
Out: "chown: changing ownership of '~/src': Operation not permitted"
```

When I tried these solutions, I unmounted and remounted the drive and restarted VSCode but they still didn't do anything.

I also read the following related questions:

1. [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/q/6723/1088830)
2. [mkdir "Permission denied' on mounted drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/973147/1088830)
3. [EACCES: permission denied in VS Code MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38980338/11151112)
4. [Failed to save file, EACCESS permision denied](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1008#issuecomment-513728248)
5. [Failed to save 'file': A system error occured (EACCES: permission denied, open 'file path')](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17860#issuecomment-306376744)
6. [ERROR: "Failed to save. Insufficient permissions." When trying to save changes in VS Code](https://askubuntu.com/q/1114453/1088830)

Running VSCode as sudo does work, but this is rather tedious and, from all the warnings I get when trying to do it, I imagine it's probably not a good idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am happy to answer any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this issue as well, try mounting your drive using the following command:

```sh
sudo mount -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),umask=0000 /dev/sda1 ~/src
```

Source: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/894424/1088830).